# Where does the Shatapatha Brahmana mention Kartikeya as son of Rudra?

Tags: vedas, shiva, gods, kartikeya, shatapatha-brahmana

I have found several websites and texts mentioning Shatapatha Brahmana says Kartikeya as son of Rudra.

Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya) also mentions the same..

> The Shatapatha Brahmana refers to him as the son of Rudra and the six faces of Rudras.

Where is it exactly mentioned in Satapatha Brahmana ?

Comment: Where is that quote from the Wikipedia? It is not there now. It mentions that there are references in Shatapatha Brahmana but not as son of Rudra "The Skanda-like motifs found in Rig Veda are found in other Vedic texts, such as section 6.1-3 of the Shatapatha Brahmana."

Answer (score 1):

The only reference I can think of is the following verse of **The Shatapatha Brahmana**.:

**Verse 6.1.3.18.:**

> *tānyetāny**aṣṭāvagnirūpāṇi** | **kumāro navamaḥ** saivāgnistrivṛttā ||*
>
> *18. These then are the **eight forms of Agni. Kumara (the boy) is the ninth:** that is Agni’s threefold state.*

It can also be symbolism to Rudra Kumara but Rudra in vedas means Agni only. Still it's damn close to the Puranic Version of Lord Kartikeya.

**Sri Shiva Purana 7.2:2:31.:**

> *70-74. **Ṣaṇmukha is born of Śiva.** He holds Śakti (Vel) and thunderbolt. **He is the son of fire.** He is also the son of Gangā, Gaṇāmbā and Kṛttikās. He is surrounded by Viśākha, Śākha and Naigameya. He is the conqueror of Indra and the demon Tāraka. He is the Generalissimo of Indra’s armies. He pierced the important mountains Meru and others with his splendour. He resembles molten gold. He has eyes resembling petals of lotuses. **He is Kumāra** and the model for all tender beings. He is the favourite of Śiva and fondly attached to Śivā. He is a perpetual worshipper of Śiva’s feet. May he grant my desire at the behest of the two.*

I hope this clarifies your queries. Prd..